# Check to see if value in first array is in second array then create a third array

Tags: php, arrays

1) posting array of checkboxes to php
2) comparing POSTED array to see is in master array.
3) if it is, then add "1" in new array
4) if it is not in the master array, then add a "0" in the new array

Here is what I have:

```
$posted_array = array("8", "9", "12", "17");

$master_array = array("8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20");

$db_input_array = array();

foreach($master_array as $key => $array_value) {
    foreach($posted_array as $posted_key => $posted_value) {
        if($array_value == $posted_value) {
            $db_input_array[$array_value] = "1"; 
        } else {
            $db_input_array[$array_value] = "0"; 
        }
    }
}

print_r($db_input_array);
```

desired result:

```
Array ( 
  [8] => 1 
  [9] => 1 
  [10] => 0 
  [11] => 0
  [12] => 1
  [13] => 0
  [14] => 0
  [15] => 0
  [16] => 0
  [17] => 1
  [18] => 0
  [19] => 0
  [20] => 0
)
```

Comment: what are the current results?

Comment: Note: php has an `array_intersect($arr1, $arr2)` which will return an array containing common elements between `$arr1` and `$arr2`.

Answer (score 3):

```
$db_input_array = array();
foreach($master_array as $m){
   if(in_array($m, $posted_array)){
      $db_input_array[$m]=1;
   }else{
      $db_input_array[$m]=0;
   }
}
```

http://codepad.org/NaW5zHe5